# Editar registro antes de passar por regra de validação no Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, request

Possuo um `form` que faz o cadastro de clientes. No campo de cadastro de *CPF*, eu formato os dados com `jQuery` inserindo a pontuação entre os dígitos. Acontece que inserindo essa formatação, minhas regras do `Requets` não funcionam corretamente.

`ClientRequest.php`

```
public function rules()
{    
    return [

            'user_create_id' => 'required|integer',
            'marital_status_id' => 'required|integer',
            'people_type' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|max:100|min:10',
            'cpf' => 'required|max:14|min:14|unique:clients',
            'rg' => 'max:13|min:6',
            'data_nasc' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:15',
            'email' => 'min:10|max:225|email',
            'has_credit_card' => 'required',
            'has_current_account' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

Onde esta a regra para o *CPF* `unique:clients`, a mesma não funciona, pois ele recebe o valor com os **pontos** e o **hífen**, assim quando busca no banco algum *CPF* igual ao informado, nunca vai achar, pois no momento de salvar no banco eu retiro esses elementos.

**Tem como eliminar os mesmos na própria regra de validação**?

Comment: Qual é a versão do seu Laravel?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Possui duas formas viáveis para trabalhar com validação com esse problema:

#### 1) Criação de [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) com [Validação Customizada](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation)

Crie um [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) pelo comando:

> `php composer make:provider UniqueDocumentServiceProvider`

dentro da pasta `app\Providers` abra o arquivo `UniqueDocumentServiceProvider.php` e coloque o código logo abaixo:

```
<?php namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class UniqueDocumentServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        //Criação de uma nova validação  
        \Validator::extend('unique_cpf', function ($attribute, 
                                                   $value, 
                                                   $parameters, 
                                                   $validator) {

            $value = str_replace(['.','-'],'', $value);
            return ((DB::table('clients')
                       ->where('cpf','=', $value)
                       ->count()) == 0 );

        });

        //Mensagem da validação customizada
        \Validator::replacer('unique_cpf', function ($message, 
                                                     $attribute, 
                                                     $rule, 
                                                     $parameters) {

            return 'CPF existente';

        });
    }    
    public function register()
    {
    }
}
```

nesse [Service Provider](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers) será feito um [Validator](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation) customizado aonde terá a opção de formatar a informação na hora da validação e com isso eliminar o problema da outra validação que pega puramente o valor enviado pelo formulário. Ao criar esse arquivo com toda essas informações, precisa ser registrado no arquivo `app\config\app.php` na chave `providers` como exemplo:

```
'providers' => [

        /*
         * Laravel Framework Service Providers...
         */
        .....

        App\Providers\UniqueDocumentServiceProvider::class

    ],
```

com esse registro vai no arquivo `ClientRequest.php` e troque `unique:clients` por `unique_cpf`:

```
public function rules()
{    
    return [

            'user_create_id' => 'required|integer',
            'marital_status_id' => 'required|integer',
            'people_type' => 'required',
            'name' => 'required|max:100|min:10',
            'cpf' => 'required|max:14|min:14|unique_cpf',
            'rg' => 'max:13|min:6',
            'data_nasc' => 'required',
            'phone' => 'required|min:10|max:15',
            'email' => 'min:10|max:225|email',
            'has_credit_card' => 'required',
            'has_current_account' => 'required',
    ];
}
```

com essas modificações terá o efeito esperado.

#### 2) Fazendo o processo manual direto no método do `Controller`

Utilize o [Request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests) (em vez do `ClientRequest`) , e antes de verificar no [\Validator::make](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation) retire os pontos e traço do seu **cpf**:

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
    $rules = [
      'name' => 'required|max:100|min:10',
      'cpf' => 'required|max:14|unique:pessoas'
    ];

    $value = $request->except('cpf');

    //removendo pontos e traço e criando a chave para validação.
    $value['cpf'] = str_replace(['.','-'], '', $request->input('cpf'));

    //Validação ...
    $validator = \Validator::make($value, $rules);

    //Se falhar retorne com os erros !!!
    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        return redirect('pessoa')
            ->withErrors($validator)
            ->withInput();
    }

    //Se passar desse if os dados são válido faça aqui as outras operações
    return $request->all();
}
```

<sub>**Observação:** método `store` é um exemplo, enfatizando como seria o código</sub>

*Então, essas são as maneiras de fazer essa validação que o dado precisa antes de ser validado, ter um formato próprio.*

***Referencias:***

- [Service Providers](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/providers)
- [Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation)
- [HTTP Requests](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/requests)
- [Form Request Validation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/validation#form-request-validation)

Comment: Boa noite @Virgilio , tudo bom  ? Deu erro ao submeter o form , acusando que o metodo não existe "Method [validateUniqueCpf] does not exist." . O que pode ser ?

Comment: Segui os passos pelo ServiceProvider , acredito que fica mais organizado. Quanto ao erro , segue o mesmo : blob:https://web.whatsapp.com/be19ebd5-ebfc-4ad9-a29f-d690e3be0de1

Comment: Sim ,registrado normal. Não sei se a versão do Laravel influencia em algo , mas estou usando a 5.3 .

Comment: Edit : Reinstalei o Laravel e o problema foi solucionado. Agradeço ao @Virgilio pela reposta completa. Vlw !!

Comment: Vlw @HenriqueFelix ...